# Problem with me menu and google talk

Tags: 10.10, ayatana

Every time I restart the computer, or resume from standby the MeMenu goes offline and won't let me change my status. The only way to make it work again is to disable Google talk and then re enable it.

Am I missing something in the settings or is this the intended operation. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I doubt it's the *intended* way to behave...

Comment: Thats what I thought. Its a shame because it renders the Me Menu useless for me.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a bug report. Please look at [Reporting Bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) for information about reporting a bug before going to [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug) to report this issue. Make sure you check for duplicates first!

You most likely want to file this bug against `telepathy-gabble`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a bug at all. Me Menu is inactive when no instant messengers is started. What status do you expect from it?

Comment: I thought that the point of having the Me Menu was so I wouldn't need to start an instant messenger every time I reboot. I expect it to be integrated into the operating system.

Comment: But without connection cannot be a status. Maybe add messenger to autostart?

Comment: The Me menu is always there when I start up. And I have an Ethernet connection.

Comment: I mean connection to some messenger (AOL, MSN, ICQ) or social network.

Comment: I don't think I understand the point your making. Isn't the Me Menu acting as a messenger?

Comment: With Empathy and libtelepathy installed , yes. With Pidgin - no. With Google Talk - dont know.